# JSON.parse don't convert a string to an object

Tags: javascript, json

Why I can't to convert a string (JSON format) to an object?

This is js function that receives a JSON formatted string from server:

```
function GetData(){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://'+ ip + ":" + port + "/api/s", true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) { 

        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            for (var i=0; i<data['result'].length; i++) {
                ...some operations here...
                }
            }

        catch(e) {
            console.log(e.message + " in " + xhr.responseText);
            return}
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

But I get string, JSON.parse not work:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in "{\"result\":[{\"id\":1, \"region\":\"\u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0410\u0434\u044b\u0433\u0435\u044f\"}, {\"id\":2, \"region\":\"\u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0411\u0430\u0448\u043a\u043e\u0440\u0442\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\"}, {\"id\":3, \"region\" ... and so on ...
```

I can't get length of JSON-object property value, can't to access to it's property 'result' and so on.

But why?

Comment: `data['result']` is undefined, but that assumes there is a result property in `data`. Have you checked the value of `xhr.responseText` and of `data` itself to see if the structure is maybe just slightly different than you expected?

Comment: there's something wrong with your JSON. check the JSON with an online json-checker: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: try console.log(data) after JSON.parse line and see the output

Comment: I think the error is in for var statement where length is called as it is where length is used. Can you please check that the error is not there. You may want to console data['result] there.

Comment: @Bee157 if there's anything wrong in that JSON then JSON.parse must have thrown the exception

Comment: @GolezTrol xhr.'responseText' and 'data' (which is the same) are just a string. Of course, I cheked it.

Comment: @YashGanatra you're right, I was too fast.

Comment: Kannan J, I tried, data['result] is just 'undefined'.

Comment: Yash Ganatra, of course, but I see only JSON-like string in console, not object.

Comment: *"xhr.'responseText' and 'data' (which is the same) "* - Which is *not* the same, because the first is the encoded, and the second one is the decoded version. They may both be string, but I can't imagine that they are actually exactly the *same* string. Please check carefully, because I imagine that that is the cause of the problem: The result of decoding your JSON, is just another string.

Comment: @GolezTrol You right, 'data' is decoded. But the real cause of the problem is already found. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `xhr.responseText` to contain a JSON encoded object. It looks like it actually contains a JSON encoded **string** (and that the JSON encoded string contains a JSON encoded object). Note the `"` characters around `xhr.responseText` when you `console.log` it.

That is to say: You have an object which has been encoded as JSON which has then been encoded as JSON **again**.

When you run `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`, you decode the first layer of JSON encoding. This gives you a string of JSON that represents an object.

That string doesn't have a `result` property.

You need to decode the second set to JSON to get your object:

```
var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data.result.length);
```

---

```js
console.log("Compare single encoded data:");
var json_obj = "{ \"result\": [] }";
console.log("JSON Object: " + json_obj);
var obj = JSON.parse(json_obj);
console.log("Object result length", obj.result.length);
console.log("-------------");
console.log("With double encoded data:");
var json_str = "\"{ \\\"result\\\": [] }\"";
console.log("JSON String (See the extra quotes?): " + json_str);
var json_obj_2 = JSON.parse(json_str);
console.log("JSON Object 2: " + json_obj_2);
var obj_2 = JSON.parse(json_obj_2);
console.log("Object 2 result length", obj.result.length);
```

---

A better solution would be to figure out why the data was being double encoded in the first place and not do that.

Comment: I cant see that the string is double time strigified.

Comment: @YashGanatra — Look closer then? I can. You can see the quotes around it when it is logged (as I said).

Comment: @Quentin Your solution is delicious! I actually had double-encoded json. Just server-side problem. Thanks a lot!